# Move a specific element in arraylist to the last index

Tags: java

Let's say I have this List

```
List<Integer> grades = Arrays.asList(9,8,1,0,7,0,0,3);
```

I want to move all zeros to the last indexes .. So I want the output to be something like:

```
9,8,1,7,3,0,0,0
```

I can do that with simple arrays but I still didn't figure out how to do that in ArrayList.

Comment: "I can do that with simple arrays" it's mostly the same, just use the correct method to `get` and the correct method to `set` (hint hint)

Comment: List<Integer> price = Arrays.asList(9,8,1,0,7,0,0,3);
       
        
        int count = 0;
        
        
        for(int i=0; i<price.size(); i++) {
         if(price.get(i) !=0) {
          
          price.set(count++, price.get(i)); 
          
         }
         
        }
          while(count<price.size()) {
              price.set(count++, 0);
             
              
             }
         System.out.print(Arrays.toString(price.toArray()));
        }

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the list accordingly using [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), to move all `0` to last and not to sort the remaining values

```
grades.sort(Comparator.comparing(value -> value == 0 ? 1 /* sort last */ : 0 /* don't sort */));  //[9, 8, 1, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: The semantics of your extractor aren't immediately obvious, and I'd request a comment (or better yet, a named constant) if I saw that in code review.

Comment: sorry you me naming `i` to proper name ? could you please elaborate your comment ? @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: I think that using `i` can be misleading, since that's usually the name of an *index* variable. Maybe use `value`, or the shorter `v`, would make the logic clearer. Perhaps you could also add comments, though I think that is overkill, e.g. `comparing(value -> value == 0 ? 1/*sort last*/ : 0/*sort first*/)`. In my opinion, creating constants for the 1 and 0 values is definitely overkill, so I disagree with chrylis on that.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas i really like the comments since it will be easy to understand for new persons

Comment: *Code style nitpick:* `value->value` looks like a C++ pointer reference (arrow operator). Please use spaces around operators, especially that one, i.e. `value -> value == 0`

Comment: @Andreas Rather, `private static final Function<Integer, Integer> ZEROES_LAST = value -> (value == 0) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: The kind of comment I'd tend to include is something like `// map all nonzero values to zero so they'll sort first, then zeroes`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- The goal is "zeroes last", so I was wondering if you misnamed the function, but you actually flipped the 0 and 1, so... *Confusing...*

Comment: @Andreas I made the mistake of also reading Mureinik's answer before entirely waking up and got the condition backwards. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, you could reuse the same code you have for arrays by using the `List`'s `get` and `set` methods instead of the `[]` operator.

Another "sneaky" approach could be to utilize the fact that sorting keeps the relative positions of two elements that are equivalent, and sort the list with a custom `Comparator` that sorts according to whether or not an item is equal to `0` - all the zeros will moved to the end, and all the other items will keep their relative postions:

```java
grades.sort(Comparator.comparing(i -> i == 0));
```

Comment: This depends on the nonobvious detail that `TRUE` is considered greater, and thus sorts later than, `FALSE`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- It is [well-documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#compareTo-java.lang.Boolean-) that the *natural order* of `Boolean` sorts `false` before `true`.

Comment: @Andreas It's certainly documented. This unquestionably clever trick of converting the zeroness into a predicate and sorting on _that_ is clever enough to warrant an explanation.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Agreed. In this case, the cleverness *(very nice, up-vote from me)* will probably confound most people, at least for a little while, so a comment like this might be good: `// sorts 0's last, since true sorts last`

Answer (score 1):

For a faster *O(n)* implementation than using an *O(n log(n))* `sort()` solution, do it the same way you'd do it for an array:

```java
int j = 0;
for (Integer value : grades) {
    if (value != 0) {
        grades.set(j++, value);
    }
}
while (j < grades.size()) {
    grades.set(j++, 0);
}
```

Of course, using `set(int, ?)` can be bad for performance if not an `ArrayList`, so it'd be better to use an updatable iterator, i.e. a `ListIterator`:

```java
ListIterator<Integer> iter = grades.listIterator();
for (Integer value : grades) {
    if (value != 0) {
        iter.next(); // No need to call hasNext() first
        iter.set(value);
    }
}
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    iter.next();
    iter.set(0);
}
```

For comparison, here is the comparable array solution:

```java
int[] grades = {9,8,1,0,7,0,0,3};

int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    if (grades[i] != 0) {
        grades[j++] = grades[i];
    }
}
while (j < grades.length) {
    grades[j++] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys ..

I managed to do it the same way I did it with simple arrays :

```
 List<Integer> price = Arrays.asList(9,8,1,0,7,0,0,3);
       
        
        int count = 0;
        
        
        for(int i=0; i<price.size(); i++) {
            if(price.get(i) !=0) {
                
                price.set(count++, price.get(i));   
                
            }
            
        }
             while(count<price.size()) {
                price.set(count++, 0);
             
                
             }
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(price.toArray()));
        }
```